# How to set the build config on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build a project in xcode .After I build it it shows me an error :

> The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains.

I google it and I found it that this error is due the build settings on Code Signing Identity .
I will attach a photo to see my configurations:

[image].

Can you help me fix this error?

thank you!

Comment: Set proper code signing identity, matching provisioning  profile and bundle identifier

Comment: I am new in xcode.All I need is to export the ios app from the project :)

Comment: go to keychain check that which certificate you have, use that as signing identity and matching provisioning profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains. -- The error is related to your **Keychain** , check your delevloper certificate is expired or not , for example If it is expired its Showing like

[image]

*Look* in your keychain (with Keychain Access). Do you or do you not have a valid up-to-date development certificate? for example

[image]

Except that the one in the screen shot is expired! You need to have one, and it needs to be *not* expired. If you don't have one, then get one.

Comment: I solved the problem changing the Ios deployment targent :) thank you!